# In boost MPL, how do I check if an operation worked as intended?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

Normally when I write code, I frequently check that what I am doing works but using some sort of assertion operation:

```
std::vector<int> a(1, 1);
std::vector<int> b = {1};
assert(a == b); // this either works, or breaks in a helpful manner
```

How do I achieve this in `boost mpl`? I'm currently trying to generate a vector of pairs from 2 vectors, where the first vector represents the keys and the 2nd the values (ie. *types*):

```
using Keys = boost::mpl::vector<double, bool, int, char, bool*>;
using Types = boost::mpl::vector<char, char, int, int, int>;

using ExpectedOutput =                                                   
    boost::mpl::vector<                                                         
        boost::mpl::pair<double, char>,                                         
        boost::mpl::pair<bool, char>,                                           
        boost::mpl::pair<int, char>,                                            
        boost::mpl::pair<char, int>,                                            
        boost::mpl::pair<bool*, int>>;

// now I perform some operation which I _think_ might work
using PairsSequence =                                                           
    typename boost::mpl::transform<                                             
        Keys,                                                            
        Types,
        boost::mpl::pair<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2>>;

// Now I attempt to check that it worked
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( boost::mpl::equal_to<PairsSequence, ExpectedPairsSequence> ));
```

But this doesn't work, presumably because the return type of `boost::mpl::transform` is some template expression. How can I force conversion of this output into a type that I can compare to an *expected* value?

How do others debug their MPL code? Boost doesn't seem to provide any facilities for checking the output of operations (or at least I don't know how to use them, `BOOST_MPL_ASSERT` being a case in point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `equal_to` [models the *Numeric Metafunction* concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/equal-to.html). You would want to use `equal`.
2. you will want to apply the metafunction before comparing, I added `::type` in the assert
3. the expected type didn't actually match, so it would fail unless you match them.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c746076a7d4689b7)**

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>


using Keys = boost::mpl::vector<double, bool, int, char, bool*>;
using Types = boost::mpl::vector<char, char, int, int, int>;

using ExpectedOutput =                                                   
    boost::mpl::vector<                                                         
        boost::mpl::pair<double, char>,                                         
        boost::mpl::pair<bool, char>,                                           
        boost::mpl::pair<int, int>,                                            
        boost::mpl::pair<char, int>,                                            
        boost::mpl::pair<bool*, int>>;

// now I perform some operation which I _think_ might work
using PairsSequence =                                                           
    typename boost::mpl::transform<                                             
        Keys,                                                            
        Types,
        boost::mpl::pair<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2>>;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( boost::mpl::equal<PairsSequence::type, ExpectedOutput> ));
```